# Inequality with a norm

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, inequality, normed-spaces

I need help with the following:

Let $A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}a & b \\c & d\end{array}\right)$, with $a\in\mathbb{R}$, $b\in(l^{1})^{*}$, $c\in l^{1}$, and $d\in L(l^{1},l^{1})$.

Let $h\in l^{1}$.

What I'm trying to show is that then

$||Ah||\leq||A||_{1}\cdot||h||$, where $||A||_{1}=\sup_{j}\sum_{i}|A_{ij}|$ (maximum absolute column sum).

My attempt so far: I recalled the definition of the operator norm

$|||A|||=\sup_{h\neq0}\frac{||Ah||}{||h||}$

and looking at itmy inequality seemed to follow by definition, since $||A||_{1}$ is an example of an operator norm, right? Can it be that simple?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, one has first to show that the right hand side of the defining equation of $\|A\|_1$, which a priori belongs to $\mathbb{R}_{\geq0} \cup \{\infty\}$, is actually a finite number. Then, establishing the inequality $\|Ah\| \leq \|A\|_1\|h\|$ for $h \in \ell^1$, we will deduce that $A \in L(\ell^1,\ell^1)$. Only then can we speak of the operator norm of $A$, and observe that in fact it equals $\|A\|_1$, as we have $|||\,B\,||| = \|B\|_1$ for all $B \in L(\ell^1,\ell^1)$.

Since $(\ell^1)^* \simeq \ell^\infty$, we identify $b \in (\ell^1)^*$ with a bounded sequence $(b_j)_{j=1}^\infty \subset \mathbb{R}$. Similarly, we view $d \in L(\ell^1,\ell^1)$ as an infinite real matrix $(d_{ij})_{i,j=1}^\infty$ for which $\|d\|_1 = \sup_{j\geq1}\sum_{i=1}^\infty|d_{ij}| < \infty$. Finally, we write $c = (c_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ and $h = (h_j)_{j=1}^\infty$. With this notation, we have 
$$ \|A\|_1 = \sup\left\{|a|+ \sum_{i=1}^\infty|c_i|,\  \sup_{j\geq1}\left(|b_j| + \sum_{i=1}^\infty|d_{ij}|\right)\right\}.$$
Since $|a|+\sum_{i=1}^\infty|c_i| = |a| + \|c\| <\infty$ and 
$$\sup_{j\geq1}\left(|b_j| + \sum_{i=1}^\infty |d_{ij}|\right) \leq \sup_{j\geq1}|b_j| + \sup_{j\geq1}\sum_{i=1}^\infty |d_{ij}| = \|b\|_\infty + \|d\|_1 < \infty,$$
we have $\|A\|_1 < \infty$ as well. Now, consider $\|Ah\|$. We have
$$\begin{multline} \|Ah\| = \left|ah_1 + \sum_{j=1}^\infty b_jh_{j+1}\right| + \sum_{i=1}^\infty\left|c_ih_1 + \sum_{j=1}^\infty d_{ij}h_{j+1}\right| \leq\\ |a|\,|h_1| + \sum_{j=1}^\infty |b_j|\,|h_{j+1}| + \sum_{i=1}^\infty\left(|c_i|\,|h_1|+\sum_{j=1}^\infty|d_{ij}|\,|h_{j+1}|\right). \end{multline}$$
Re-grouping the terms in the above expression and changing the order of summation in the convergent double series with non-negative terms $\sum_{i=1}^\infty\sum_{j=1}^\infty |d_{ij}|\,|h_{j+1}|$, we obtain the estimate
$$\begin{multline} \|Ah\| \leq \left(|a| + \sum_{i=1}^\infty|c_i|\right)|h_1| + \sum_{j=1}^\infty\left(|b_j| + \sum_{i=1}^\infty|d_{ij}|\right)|h_{j+1}| \leq\\ \|A\|_1|h_1| + \sum_{j=1}^\infty\|A\|_1|h_{j+1}| = \|A\|_1\|h\|, \end{multline}$$
as required.

Comment: thank you for an extensive answer!

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: just one quick question, what would be a way to show that $l^{1}$ is isomorphic to $l^{\infty}$?

Comment: The space $\ell^\infty$ is isomorphic to $(\ell^1)^*$ (the dual of $\ell^1$). Given an element $u\in\ell^\infty$, define a linear functional $u^\flat:\ell^1\to\mathbb{R}$ via the rule $$u^\flat(x)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty u_ix_i$$ for $x\in\ell^1$. Since $|u^\flat(x)| \leq \sum_i|u_i|\,|x_i|\leq\sum_i\left(\sup_j|u_j|\right)|x_j|=\|u\|_\infty\|x\|< \infty$, we deduce that $u^\flat(x)$ is correctly defined (i.e. that the series on the right in the definition of $u^\flat$ converges), and that $u^\flat$ is bounded, with $\|u^\flat\|\leq\|u\|_\infty$. (to be continued)

Comment: Since $u^\flat$ depends linearly on $u$, we have defined a continuous linear map $(-)^\flat:\ell^\infty\to(\ell^1)^*$. Now, suppose that $f \in \ell^1$, and for $j \in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}$ let $e^j \in \ell^1$ be the sequence with terms $(e^j)_i = 0$ if $i \neq j$, and $(e^j)_j = 1$. Let $f^\sharp \in \ell^\infty$ be the sequence with terms $$(f^\sharp)_i = f(e^i).$$ Since $f$ is bounded and $\|e^i\| = 1$, we have $|(f^\sharp)_i| \leq \|f\|$ for all $i$. Hence, $f^\sharp$ is indeed bounded, with $\|f^\sharp\|_\infty \leq \|f\|$. (to be continued)

Comment: Since $f^\sharp$ depends linearly on $f$, we have a continuous linear map $(-)^\sharp : (\ell^1)^* \to \ell^\infty$. Clearly, $(u^\flat)^\sharp = u$ for every $u \in \ell^\infty$. On the other hand, suppose that $f \in (\ell^1)^*$. Given $x = (x_i)_{i=1}^\infty \in \ell^1$, define a sequence $(x^n)_{n=1}^\infty$ of elements of $\ell^1$ via the rule $$x^n = \sum_{j=1}^n x_j e^j = (x_1,\ldots,x_n,0,0,\ldots).$$ Since $\|x^n-x\| = \sum_{i>n} |x_i| \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$, we have $\lim_{n\to\infty} x^n = x$ in $\ell^1$. (to be continued)

Comment: Therefore, $$f(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty} f(x^n) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n f(e^i)x_i = \sum_{i=1}^\infty (f^\sharp)_i x_i.$$ This shows that $(f^\sharp)^\flat = f$. Hence, $(-)^\flat$ and $(-)^\sharp$ are mutually inverse continuous isomorphisms between $\ell^\infty$ and $(\ell^1)^*$.

Comment: Also, the inequalities $\|u^\flat\| \leq \|u\|_\infty = \|(u^\flat)^\sharp\|_\infty \leq \|u^\flat\|$ imply that $\|u^\flat\| = \|u\|_\infty$ for $u \in \ell^\infty$. Similarly, $\|f^\sharp\|_\infty = \|f\|$ for $f \in (\ell^1)^*$. Therefore, $(-)^\sharp$ and $(-)^\flat$ are actually isometries.